# Is there a way to use a part of varchar2 string as a primary key in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to connect two tables by two columns.

First table has primary key as integer type id.

Second table has varchar2 type column which contains the same primary key but is located in the middle of a string.

> For example in first table I have column called integer ID with ID
>   like 1234. In the second table I have column with string like
>   'abcdefgh - 1234 (ijklmno)'.

Is there a way to use that nested key?

Comment: It's a bad idea to put table1's id as a part of a table2 column. Have an int column in table2, foreign key to table1!

Comment: Is the pattern always same for the column containing primary key as string?

Comment: @jarlh I didn't designed these tables. It was created long ago.

Comment: if the pattern is always same for second table column then it is possible to do

Comment: @ Rahul Tripathi In fact there are diffrent patterns but I need to use only one of them so in the end - yes.

Comment: If *part* of the varchar column is a candidate key, the rest of that column will be functionally dependent on that CK. (just like the other columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [regexp_replace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions115.htm). try this query

```
select * from table1
where table1.ID in (select regexp_replace(column2, '[A-Za-z]') from table2)
```

syntax of regexp_replace is
 `REGEXP_REPLACE(string, target [, replacement [, position [, occurrence [, regexp_modifiers]]]])`

Comment: In fact I used regexp_substr instead regexp_replace if anyone will have similiar problem to mine but your answer directed me to the solution.

Comment: using **regexp_substr** is really a good idea.let me edit my answer

Answer (score 3):

From Oracle 11g you can use a virtual column:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30645/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
  id NUMBER(4,0) PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ( 1234 );

CREATE TABLE TableB (
  data VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL
                    CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE( data, '\w+ - (0|[1-9]\d{0,3}) \(\w+\)' ) ),
  id   NUMBER(4,0)  GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( data, '\w+ - (0|[1-9]\d{0,3}) \(\w+\)', 1, 1, null, 1 ) ) ) VIRTUAL,
  CONSTRAINT TableB__ID__FK FOREIGN KEY ( id ) REFERENCES TableA ( id )
);

INSERT INTO TableB ( data ) VALUES ( 'abcdefgh - 1234 (ijklmno)' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM TableB
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30645/1/0)**:

```
|                      DATA |   ID |
|---------------------------|------|
| abcdefgh - 1234 (ijklmno) | 1234 |
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is Oracle 10gR2.

Comment: @Lukasz-K2 Then you can't use VIRTUAL columns. You could either change the table design, which is a permanent solution. Or, use the workaround as I have mentioned in my answer. Or, upgrade to 11g and use MTO's solution which is also a good option.

Comment: You can also add a permenant non-virtual column for the `ID` and ensure consistency using a trigger on updates and inserts (which would be an attempt to duplicate the behavior of a virtual column). You can then apply foreign keys to this column. Triggers have their place but I tend to avoid using them so, while it is a solution, I don't find it appealing.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the table **design** is bad. You should have the **primary key** column with a **foreign key relationship** in the second table. And have a **supporting index** for the foreign key. Storing **delimited text** in a **single column** is not a good design and violates **normalization**.

If the pattern of the string is same for all the rows in the second table, then you could use **SUBSTR** to extract the required string and then **join** with the first table.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH t(str) AS(
  2  SELECT 'abcdefgh - 1234 (ijklmno)' FROM dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT substr(str, 12, 4) new_str FROM t;

NEW_
----
1234

SQL>
```

You could join `substr(str, 12, 4)` with the primary key of the first table,

```
SELECT column_list
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2
ON (t1.primary_key = substr(column_name, 12, 4)
WHERE ...
```

From **performance point of view**, you need to create a **function-based index** on the column in second table:

```
CREATE INDEX fn_idx_col ON table_2(substr(column_name, 12, 4));
```

From 11g onwards, `VIRTUAL COLUMN` is introduced. However, creating an **index** on the **virtual column** is same as creating a **function-based index** on a static column.

**NOTE** Since you do not have a foreign key relationship, you will always end up with **tablescans on both the tables**. If you have the proper relationships, then *ideally* **Oracle would only use the primary key of the first table and avoid any table scan on the second table**.

Comment: You can also create foreign key constraints based on virtual columns, that is no problem.

Comment: @Wernfried Yeah, but OP is on 10g. So, didn't get deeper into it.